# Celery revoke_by_stamped_headers doesn't work into the Django signal

Tags: django, django-celery, django-signals

I try to revoke celery task using *revoke_by_stamped_headers*. When *app.control.revoke_by_stamped_headers* is inside if block with *stamped_task* it works.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bet)
def send_prepared_notifications(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    """Send prepared push notifications.

    Args:
        sender (Bet): The sender.
        instance (Bet): The instance.
        created (bool): Whether the instance was created.
    """

    class MonitoringIdStampingVisitor(StampingVisitor):
        def on_signature(self, sig, **headers) -> dict:
            return {"bet_id": str(instance.id), "stamped_headers": ["bet_id"]}

    if created:
        daily_config = DailyBetConfig.objects.last()

        bet_added_message, _ = PushMessage.objects.get_or_create(
            type="bet added", defaults={"title": "Bet added", "body": "Bet added"}
        )
        start_added_bet_progress = instance.start_date_time - timedelta(hours=daily_config.event_added_diff)

        def start():
            stamped_task = send_push_notification_active_devices.s(bet_added_message.title, bet_added_message.body)
            stamped_task.stamp(visitor=MonitoringIdStampingVisitor())

            stamped_task.apply_async(
                eta=start_added_bet_progress,
                expires=instance.start_date_time,
                ignore_result=True,
            )

        transaction.on_commit(lambda: start())

    else:
        app.control.revoke_by_stamped_headers(headers={"bet_id": [str(instance.id)]}, terminate=True, signal="SIGKILL")
```

I am expecting to revoke celery task if Bet object is exist.